# Cypress: Typescript custom commands not working

Tags: typescript, cypress

**Update:**
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1065#issuecomment-351769720
Removing an import from my commands.ts fixed it. Thanks

I'm trying to convert my cypress project to use TypeScript. I'm following the info on https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands

I've fixed all the other compilation errors I was getting but I'm still unable to get any of my custom commands to work for example:

**commands.ts:**

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    clickByLinkText(link: string): Chainable<Element>;
  }
}

// Finds and clicks a given link by it's link text
Cypress.Commands.add("clickByLinkText", (link: string) => {
  cy.get("a").contains(link).click();
});
```

When I try to call the function in my test I get:

> TS2339: Property 'clickByLinkText' does not exist on type 'cy &
> EventEmitter'.

I have **import "./commands";** in my support/index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your custom commands like this. You can check out the discussion here - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1065#issuecomment-351769720 -

```
function clickByLinkText(link: string) {
  cy.get("a").contains(link).click();
}
Cypress.Commands.add("clickByLinkText", clickByLinkText)
```

Also in your tsconfig.json file add `"node_modules/cypress"` under `includes`, considering node_modules and tsconfig.json file are at the sam level.

Comment: Are you sure? That's not how it works on the example and looking at other repos I can't see them doing it like that.

Comment: Hey, I added a GitHub thread to the answer. I was facing the same issue as you, I was able to resolve it by these two changes.

Comment: Thanks, by removing the import from my commands.ts I fixed it (well I have more errors to fix but at least not around my commands)